# CF deploy failure Can't find property dea_next.advertise_interval_in_seconds

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, cloud-foundry, haproxy

I'm trying to setup CloudFoundry, I follwed the steps for setting up the environment fro Bosh Lite and had uploaded the stemcells. When I deploy CF, I get a failure message `Can't find property dea_next.advertise_interval_in_seconds` and the bosh task fails.

When I check the running vms, I can see `ha_proxy` running on 10.244.0.34 but establishing a connection with `cf` fails!

Bellow is the full output of the deployment operation:

```
$ bosh deploy

Processing deployment manifest
------------------------------
Getting deployment properties from director...
Unable to get properties list from director, trying without it...
Compiling deployment manifest...
Cannot get current deployment information from director, possibly a new deployment
Please review all changes carefully

Deploying
---------
Deployment name: `cf-manifest.yml'
Director name: `Bosh Lite Director'
Are you sure you want to deploy? (type 'yes' to continue): yes

Director task 3
  Started preparing deployment
  Started preparing deployment > Binding deployment. Done (00:00:00)
  Started preparing deployment > Binding releases. Done (00:00:00)
  Started preparing deployment > Binding existing deployment. Done (00:00:00)
  Started preparing deployment > Binding resource pools. Done (00:00:00)
  Started preparing deployment > Binding stemcells. Done (00:00:00)
  Started preparing deployment > Binding templates. Done (00:00:00)
  Started preparing deployment > Binding properties. Done (00:00:00)
  Started preparing deployment > Binding unallocated VMs. Done (00:00:00)
  Started preparing deployment > Binding instance networks. Done (00:00:00)
     Done preparing deployment (00:00:00)

  Started preparing package compilation > Finding packages to compile. Done (00:00:01)

  Started compiling packages
  Started compiling packages > cli/8870a5c3c03b4d4f2e190c3d81e3805d8b2e100a
  Started compiling packages > buildpack_cache/4ced0bc62f12dcaa79121718ca3525253ede33b5
  Started compiling packages > rootfs_lucid64/362ed9221fbdae9cd3f889088fc373b04f04cb8f
  Started compiling packages > buildpack_php/6ee814b62c4f7a587fdb75f0aeee6775cbb95690
  Started compiling packages > buildpack_python/0c0bf75e84a4a57080619175ed2e9d3bb48397c3
  Started compiling packages > buildpack_go/cb35d33ef9d379246bcdcccdad7858f8f37ab8cb
     Done compiling packages > cli/8870a5c3c03b4d4f2e190c3d81e3805d8b2e100a (00:01:24)
  Started compiling packages > buildpack_nodejs/d243df46ac9056320914ca1d6843e112b309720d
     Done compiling packages > buildpack_cache/4ced0bc62f12dcaa79121718ca3525253ede33b5 (00:02:49)
  Started compiling packages > buildpack_ruby/45668ee6b3d2777393c85807c9456e6f3437f481
     Done compiling packages > buildpack_php/6ee814b62c4f7a587fdb75f0aeee6775cbb95690 (00:05:49)
  Started compiling packages > buildpack_java_offline/0386a6f0df31247acf5a077a6b2051ec9546d641
     Done compiling packages > buildpack_python/0c0bf75e84a4a57080619175ed2e9d3bb48397c3 (00:06:34)
  Started compiling packages > buildpack_java/9b8537ab662d136ce449dc8715344ea77b24c714. Done (00:00:02)
  Started compiling packages > nginx/c916c10937c83a8be507d3100133101eb403c826
     Done compiling packages > buildpack_nodejs/d243df46ac9056320914ca1d6843e112b309720d (00:08:06)
  Started compiling packages > ruby-2.1.4/5a4612011cb6b8338d384acc7802367ae5e11003
     Done compiling packages > nginx/c916c10937c83a8be507d3100133101eb403c826 (00:03:06)
  Started compiling packages > mysqlclient/8b5d9ce287341048377997a9b3fe4ff3e6a1c68f. Done (00:00:05)
  Started compiling packages > libpq/49cc7477fcf9a3fef7a1f61e1494b32288587ed8
     Done compiling packages > buildpack_java_offline/0386a6f0df31247acf5a077a6b2051ec9546d641 (00:04:03)
  Started compiling packages > postgres/b63fe0176a93609bd4ba44751ea490a3ee0f646c. Done (00:00:19)
  Started compiling packages > debian_nfs_server/aac05f22582b2f9faa6840da056084ed15772594. Done (00:00:03)
  Started compiling packages > ruby/cd102a7fe440fd9eaeee99c6bc460b06884cbda6
     Done compiling packages > rootfs_lucid64/362ed9221fbdae9cd3f889088fc373b04f04cb8f (00:11:11)
  Started compiling packages > golang1.3/e4b65bcb478d9bea1f9c92042346539713551a4a
     Done compiling packages > libpq/49cc7477fcf9a3fef7a1f61e1494b32288587ed8 (00:01:33)
  Started compiling packages > common/43595236d1ce5f9a6120198108c226c07ab17012.Done (00:00:03)
  Started compiling packages > haproxy/630ad6d6e1d3cab4547ce104f3019b483f354613
     Done compiling packages > golang1.3/e4b65bcb478d9bea1f9c92042346539713551a4a (00:00:47)
  Started compiling packages > smoke-tests/d1aaf8be8786ee2ee001ce0a30d154c268f770fc. Done (00:00:13)
  Started compiling packages > acceptance-tests/0bfc921229a8bd4fada3aff13a0da387e3287324. Done (00:00:23)
  Started compiling packages > gorouter/68a763ef18b39c6dc2539d2a733e1721b7fa9556. Done (00:00:17)
  Started compiling packages > loggregator_trafficcontroller/cc2a209b2256500f987001771c0443b48a722780
     Done compiling packages > buildpack_go/cb35d33ef9d379246bcdcccdad7858f8f37ab8cb (00:13:16)
  Started compiling packages > syslog_drain_binder/8c627a89c81b429ea065ca86cf603204ba5eb6af
     Done compiling packages > loggregator_trafficcontroller/cc2a209b2256500f987001771c0443b48a722780 (00:00:33)
  Started compiling packages > doppler/554c3407d12b98e7175417af2db2e0eab977344c
     Done compiling packages > syslog_drain_binder/8c627a89c81b429ea065ca86cf603204ba5eb6af (00:00:15)
  Started compiling packages > dea_logging_agent/d0dba8b83454a52ebe60794d13f834243f4c932f
     Done compiling packages > doppler/554c3407d12b98e7175417af2db2e0eab977344c(00:00:18)
  Started compiling packages > hm9000/ce5b3ae4b0fa4ece6c5e741fd9b675751e78eb73
     Done compiling packages > dea_logging_agent/d0dba8b83454a52ebe60794d13f834243f4c932f (00:00:24)
  Started compiling packages > etcd_metrics_server/64efbbfb5761d09a24dad21ecfebd8824b99d433. Done (00:00:26)
  Started compiling packages > etcd/44df7612404c5b2ecc1f167126b9e0b20481f79d
     Done compiling packages > hm9000/ce5b3ae4b0fa4ece6c5e741fd9b675751e78eb73 (00:00:39)
  Started compiling packages > gnatsd/a0d6f5d3264aa8ecadb52d3bfa04540636800820
     Done compiling packages > haproxy/630ad6d6e1d3cab4547ce104f3019b483f354613(00:03:20)
  Started compiling packages > metron_agent/17b67c312bd6f5483a6cbbbfc3c42aca57088b1a
     Done compiling packages > gnatsd/a0d6f5d3264aa8ecadb52d3bfa04540636800820 (00:00:27)
     Done compiling packages > etcd/44df7612404c5b2ecc1f167126b9e0b20481f79d (00:00:35)
     Done compiling packages > metron_agent/17b67c312bd6f5483a6cbbbfc3c42aca57088b1a (00:00:20)
     Done compiling packages > buildpack_ruby/45668ee6b3d2777393c85807c9456e6f3437f481 (00:12:41)
     Done compiling packages > ruby/cd102a7fe440fd9eaeee99c6bc460b06884cbda6 (00:07:27)
  Started compiling packages > warden/7d6d68c3f52d9a0925171f879e953b352bbf1325
  Started compiling packages > login/f2f60e4ae26ec74ddb2b6ae50aefe47517267fab
  Started compiling packages > dea_next/eab1b7674e16dc7d73d0d085e8fe48e2cc7e1e9c

  Started compiling packages > collector/9fa967f02b3dacc621369babb1a5e0b7940a9c80
  Started compiling packages > uaa/263a72b91dfb6e4e9a2983e50694b5536e81c0bb
     Done compiling packages > warden/7d6d68c3f52d9a0925171f879e953b352bbf1325 (00:01:12)
  Started compiling packages > nats/cc6bda829a77ab2321c0c216aa9107aca92c3b1a. Done (00:00:30)
     Done compiling packages > uaa/263a72b91dfb6e4e9a2983e50694b5536e81c0bb (00:01:55)
     Done compiling packages > ruby-2.1.4/5a4612011cb6b8338d384acc7802367ae5e11003 (00:10:13)
  Started compiling packages > nginx_newrelic_plugin/92f2c6fb3f807f030d989c52cd1de445eba3f296
  Started compiling packages > cloud_controller_ng/02b6f1b3979031871c4821ccc911748aef03c4f1
     Done compiling packages > nginx_newrelic_plugin/92f2c6fb3f807f030d989c52cd1de445eba3f296 (00:00:10)
     Done compiling packages > login/f2f60e4ae26ec74ddb2b6ae50aefe47517267fab (00:02:16)
     Done compiling packages > collector/9fa967f02b3dacc621369babb1a5e0b7940a9c80 (00:03:18)
     Done compiling packages > dea_next/eab1b7674e16dc7d73d0d085e8fe48e2cc7e1e9c (00:03:46)
     Done compiling packages > cloud_controller_ng/02b6f1b3979031871c4821ccc911748aef03c4f1 (00:02:27)
     Done compiling packages (00:22:10)

  Started preparing dns > Binding DNS. Done (00:00:00)

  Started creating bound missing vms
  Started creating bound missing vms > small_z1/0
  Started creating bound missing vms > medium_z1/0
  Started creating bound missing vms > medium_z1/1
  Started creating bound missing vms > medium_z1/2
  Started creating bound missing vms > medium_z1/3
  Started creating bound missing vms > medium_z1/4
  Started creating bound missing vms > medium_z1/5
  Started creating bound missing vms > medium_z1/6
  Started creating bound missing vms > large_z1/0
  Started creating bound missing vms > router_z1/0
  Started creating bound missing vms > runner_z1/0
  Started creating bound missing vms > router_z1/1
     Done creating bound missing vms > runner_z1/0 (00:00:03)
     Done creating bound missing vms > medium_z1/2 (00:00:04)
     Done creating bound missing vms > medium_z1/6 (00:00:05)
     Done creating bound missing vms > router_z1/1 (00:00:04)
     Done creating bound missing vms > large_z1/0 (00:00:05)
     Done creating bound missing vms > small_z1/0 (00:00:05)
     Done creating bound missing vms > medium_z1/5 (00:00:05)
     Done creating bound missing vms > medium_z1/4 (00:00:05)
     Done creating bound missing vms > router_z1/0 (00:00:04)
     Done creating bound missing vms > medium_z1/1 (00:00:05)
     Done creating bound missing vms > medium_z1/0 (00:00:06)
     Done creating bound missing vms > medium_z1/3 (00:00:06)
     Done creating bound missing vms (00:00:06)

  Started binding instance vms
  Started binding instance vms > ha_proxy_z1/0
  Started binding instance vms > nats_z1/0
  Started binding instance vms > etcd_z1/0
  Started binding instance vms > postgres_z1/0
  Started binding instance vms > uaa_z1/0
  Started binding instance vms > login_z1/0
  Started binding instance vms > api_z1/0
  Started binding instance vms > hm9000_z1/0
  Started binding instance vms > runner_z1/0
  Started binding instance vms > loggregator_z1/0
  Started binding instance vms > loggregator_trafficcontroller_z1/0
  Started binding instance vms > router_z1/0
     Done binding instance vms > etcd_z1/0 (00:00:01)
     Done binding instance vms > hm9000_z1/0 (00:00:01)
     Done binding instance vms > runner_z1/0 (00:00:01)
     Done binding instance vms > login_z1/0 (00:00:01)
     Done binding instance vms > uaa_z1/0 (00:00:01)
     Done binding instance vms > postgres_z1/0 (00:00:01)
     Done binding instance vms > ha_proxy_z1/0 (00:00:01)
     Done binding instance vms > api_z1/0 (00:00:01)
     Done binding instance vms > router_z1/0 (00:00:01)
     Done binding instance vms > loggregator_z1/0 (00:00:01)
     Done binding instance vms > nats_z1/0 (00:00:01)
     Done binding instance vms > loggregator_trafficcontroller_z1/0(00:00:01)
     Done binding instance vms (00:00:01)

  Started preparing configuration > Binding configuration. Failed: Error filling in template `cloud_controller_api.yml.erb' for `api_z1/0' (line 271: Can't find property `["dea_next.advertise_interval_in_seconds"]') (00:00:01)

Error 100: Error filling in template `cloud_controller_api.yml.erb' for `api_z1/0' (line 271: Can't find property`["dea_next.advertise_interval_in_seconds"]')

Task 3 error

For a more detailed error report, run: bosh task 3 --debug
```

What I'm missing that may cause this failure?

Comment: What release tag are you using? The `dea_next.advertise_interval_in_seconds` property is fairly new and it seems like there was a window where there was no default specified. I tried it with v200 and had no problem deploying.

Comment: I think it was an issue in the manifest generated by `spiff`, i managed to get rid of this error message.